# matching and extracting elements with two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have a data frame that I performed clustering and have the result in one column like:

`> head(kdata)
      ID cluster    code    longt    latit
1 410001       2 1003035 -87.7316 41.73827
2 410002       3 1001655 -87.6274 41.80555
3 410007       3 1002658 -87.6321 41.68163
4 410030       3 1001218 -87.7181 41.89198
5 410033       3 1002393 -87.9277 43.02118
6 410037       3 1001039 -87.9560 43.12313`

I have another data frame that looks like this:

`> head(gdata)
            code Month Year MonthKpi.3.1   MonthKpi.4 MonthKpi.7 MonthKpi.8 MonthKpi.9
7959973  1001218     1 2010  -4721.50943 -0.743661905 0.06113550 0.15366151  0.2892823
5256388  1001039     1 2010  -1180.66667 -0.081875509 0.06277033 0.09753102  0.3749104
19304425 1001978     1 2010    -67.46296 -0.006731238 0.01908687 0.06382502  0.6990651
592175   1000107     1 2010    458.61538  0.019967915 0.11607883 0.13124782  0.3024831
32464177 1002863     1 2010  -4037.80000 -0.492330578 0.02269961 0.10713102  0.3161038
18160046 1001900     1 2010  -3232.09091 -0.499757020 0.07833606 0.11517690  0.3062926`

The data frame "gdata" contains the **same** codes (as in kdata), but repeated more than once (some are repeated 36 times, some 35, etc.). What I want to do is to create a new column in gdata that contains the corresponding cluster, extracted from kdata. Note that the size of gdata and kdata are not equal, as I have already mentioned, the **codes** in gdata are all found in kdata, but they are repeated many times to make the size of gdata much larger than kdata.

So the desired result would be:

`> head(gdata)`

```
      `code   Month Year MonthKpi.3.1   MonthKpi.4 MonthKpi.7 MonthKpi.8 MonthKpi.9 cluster`
```

`7959973  1001218     1 2010  -4721.50943 -0.743661905 0.06113550 0.15366151  0.2892823   2
5256388  1001039     1 2010  -1180.66667 -0.081875509 0.06277033 0.09753102  0.3749104   3
19304425 1001978     1 2010    -67.46296 -0.006731238 0.01908687 0.06382502  0.6990651   2
592175   1000107     1 2010    458.61538  0.019967915 0.11607883 0.13124782  0.3024831   1
32464177 1002863     1 2010  -4037.80000 -0.492330578 0.02269961 0.10713102  0.3161038   1
18160046 1001900     1 2010  -3232.09091 -0.499757020 0.07833606 0.11517690  0.3062926   1`

Let me add the fact that I would like to retain the sequence of my observations in **gdata**, after appending the "cluster" column (i.e. I don't want to have similar **codes** to be put next to each other.
Thank you

Comment: Seems like you want to do the right join. This can be easily done by join(kdata, qdata, by = "code", type = "right), from plyr package

Comment: @won782 thanks, it works, but it messed up the sequence of the data in 'gdata', which I don't want this to happen. Is there any way to retain the sequence of the data in 'gdata' data frame?

Comment: If gdata is data frame (most likely), sort by row.names(gdata). Original row names will be preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `merge`:

```
merge(gdata, kdata[c("cluster", "code")], by = "code", sort = FALSE)
```

The result:

```
     code Month Year MonthKpi.3.1  MonthKpi.4 MonthKpi.7 MonthKpi.8
1 1001218     1 2010    -4721.509 -0.74366190 0.06113550 0.15366151
2 1001039     1 2010    -1180.667 -0.08187551 0.06277033 0.09753102
  MonthKpi.9 cluster
1  0.2892823       3
2  0.3749104       3
```

Note. In your example, not all codes of `kdata` are present in `gdata`. With your actual data, the resulting data frame will have the same number of rows as `gdata`.

Comment: Thank you, but this solution doesn't retain the sequence of 'gdata' either (as is the case in won872 answer). Your code put all the similar **codes** next to each other and in increasing order. Is there any way to prevent this to happen?

Comment: @H_A You have to use `sort = FALSE`. See the update of my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I was just reading and found out that the merge function can't preserve the order (`sort= F`) only doesn't 'sort' the elements, it doesn't preserve the order. I found a solution online from this website: http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/01/merging-two-data-frame-objects-while-preserving-the-rows-order/